# How to stop callback when one evend binds another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have tkinter canvas frame in wchich left mouse button is binded to some action

```
canvas_frame = tk.Canvas(self)  # Master is tk.Frame

self.canvas_frame.tag_bind('some_tag', '<ButtonPress-1>', self.some_action)

def some_action(self):
    #do something
    self.canvas_frame.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.another_action)
```

Whenever i left click `some_tag`, `another action` is executed. Even with the first click when `another_action` is initially binded.

Is there a way to prevent `another_action` from execution?

Comment: Use: `self.canvas_frame.after(0, self.canvas_frame.bind, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.another_action)` to allow the current event to finish.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this, whichever is most appropriate will depend on your use case.

1. Rather than binding self.another_action in the buttonPress-1, bind it in buttonRelease-1.
2. Bind it as you are doing, but have a local variable in self.another_action which keeps track of the first call and simply does nothing (returns) on the first call.
3. Rather than setting the binding in buttonPress-1, instead set a variable that indicates the additional binding should be made.  Then make the binding elsewhere, e.g. in the next call by Tk.after()